# In Roll for Shoes Prison Module, how much hp should each character have?

Tags: roll-for-shoes

The "Prison Module" module (given out free in 2020) offers a variant rule for Roll For Shoes involving wounds and scars: you take a wound when you are attacked, hit by a trap, or fail a dangerous action, and if you take a second wound in the same place, it becomes a scar that cannot be healed anymore. It says that if you take as many scars as you have HP, you die. However, I cannot find in the module anywhere how much HP you have. Should I just have them roll a d6? Do I set an HP level based on their class? Or what was the intent here?

Comment: FWIW, I can confirm that the PDF apparently doesn't say or even hint anywhere how many HP characters should have, even though the paragraph at the end of the wounds and scars rules kind of sets the expectation that it should. Maybe something got lost in the editing?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Good to know i'm not just missing something obvious :) I am now wondering if maybe this system came from somewhere and only half of it got put in or something...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I spoke with the creator of the module on facebook; he said he'd set it to about 3 or 4, because the module is meant to be survivable easily for new players. Err on the side of 4, and there are optional bandages available later in the module that can restore a wound or two.

[image: facebook evidence 1]

[image]